# Blazor WASM wwwroot/appsettings.json not present in template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0) article Blazor WASM loads configuration by default from wwwroot/appsettings.json and wwwroot/appsettings.{environment}.json . However, when I generate Blazor WASM apps there are no such files under wwwroot. My dotnet version is 5.0.101, I am on Ubuntu 20.04, and my target framework is net5.0 . I do see files with such names in the Server project when I create a template hosted by ASP.NET core. Is that what it's actually referring to, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see what happened. I misread the docs; there are appsettings.json files under wwwroot if you had the `-au Individual` flag to a blazor wasm app that is **not** hosted by asp.net core.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  In case you need a template, here is a basic template:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabase": "Server=???;Initial Catalog=???;User ID=???;Password=???",
  },

  "ApiSettings": {
    "SomeApiValue": "Some API value"
  }
}
```